# How to maintain argument type in eval command

Tags: tcl

Let's say I have this:

```
set arg {{e1 e2}}
eval puts $arg
```

Because eval command concatenates its arguments first, $arg becomes {e1 e2}.

How can I keep the argument intact in calling eval? In the above example, I want $arg still be {{e1 e2}}.

Specifically, my situation is like this:

```
proc p1 {cmd arg} {
  eval $cmd $arg
}
```

So both the command name and its argument are passed into this proc. Command name is always a literal value, so it is not a problem. The key is I want the argument'e data integrity intact in calling eval.

Comment: What problem are you solving with `eval`? In modern Tcl using `eval` is often (not always, but often) a sign that something could be simplified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
% set arg {{e1 e2}}
{e1 e2}
% eval { puts $arg }
{e1 e2}
% # Or use 'list' command to make them not to be get expanded.
% eval [ list puts $arg ] 
{e1 e2}
%
```

Applying this logic as per your proc, it can be anything of the following

```
% proc p1 { cmd arg } {
    eval { $cmd $arg } 
}
% p1 puts {{e1 e2}}
{e1 e2}
%     
% proc p2 { cmd arg } { 
    eval [ list $cmd $arg ] 
}
% p2 puts {{e1 e2}}
{e1 e2}
% proc p3 { cmd arg } { 
    eval $cmd [ list $arg ] 
}
% p3 puts {{e1 e2}}
{e1 e2}
%
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to give command name and its argument in double quotes separately.

Tcl will consider them as two separate strings.